# How to add numbers asked from an input in For loop on Python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

My homework assignment is to calculate the sum of a series of numbers inputted by the user using a 'For Loop', but I can't seem to successfully add the input numbers.

I have tried printing the variable that holds the amount of numbers the loop repeats, and using things like "1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5", but it either prints every time the code loops, or it prints "15", for example. This is the code:

```
listo = (1,2,3,4,5)

for num in range(len(listo)) :
 float(input("Enter a number: "))
 krab = #This is where I'm struggling, as I don't know how to add the inputted numbers.
print "Your total sum is" , krab
```

The output should be the sum of each time it loops, so if the inputted numbers are, for example, 5 through 10, the program should print "35".

Comment: What else did you expect to be the result of `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5`?

Comment: @KlausD. I want to sum the numbers of the inputs, not the actual numbers. Sorry if that was confusing.

Answer (score 1):

```
listo = [1,2,3,4,5] #or you can just do x=5

krab = 0.0

for n in range(len(listo)) :   #range(0,x):

      num = float(input("Enter a number: "))

      krab = num + krab '''this will add the provided number with the present value of krab'''

 print("Your sum is " , krab)
```

Comment: This actually worked, but the code added each number with 'krab' (sorry for the weird name, haha) instead of the 5 numbers being added. Thank you!

Comment: Which five numbers do you want to be added? The ones in listo or the ones in the input?

Comment: The numbers in the input

Comment: It will add the inputed numbers